# Using Template Function for int, float and char for finding the lowest value

Tags: c++, function, sorting, templates

Prompt:
Convert the functions theSmallest() and fill_array()to template functions.
Test your template functions with 3 different data types:  int, float and char.

Problem:
When I load this into the compiler, there are no errors. It works for INT and Float; however when I run the index_of_smallest function for the character option... it doesn't like it. When I actually check with a "cout" what the value for min is during a char call, it is giving me "-10002e89..". That value never changes so in the for loop the index_of_min is always 0 so the compiler thinks that the smallest character is always at the index of 0.

CODE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
const int DECLARED_SIZE = 20;

template <class BaseType>
int index_of_smallest(BaseType a[], int size, int& number_used)
{
    BaseType min = a[0];
    int index_of_min = 0;
    cout << index_of_min<< endl;
    for (int index = 1 ; index < number_used; index++)
    {
        if (a[index] < min)
        {
            min = a[index];
            index_of_min = index;
        }
    }
    cout << index_of_min<< endl;
    return  index_of_min;
}

template <class BaseType>
void fill_array(BaseType a[], int size, int& number_used)
{ 
    int index = 0;
    BaseType ans;

    cout << "Enter up to " << size << " of the Data Type selected.\n"
         << "Mark the end of a list of numbers with a negative number.\n"
         << "Mark the end of a list of characters with the negative symbol \"-\". \n" 
         << "Separate each input with a space. \n" << endl;
    cin >> ans;

    while (ans >= 0 && ans != '-')
    {
        a[index] = ans;
        index++;
        cin >> ans;
    }
    number_used = index;
}

void menu()
{
    int number_used, choice, smallest, result;
    int start_index = 0;
    char menuLoop = 'Y';

    while (toupper(menuLoop) == 'Y')
    {
        cout << "Please select a type of Input: \n"
             << "1. Integers (1, 2, 3, 4, etc..)\n"
             << "2. Decimals (1.0, 2.0, 3.0. 4.0, etc..)\n"
             << "3. Characters ( a, b, c, d, etc...)\n\n\n";
        cin >> choice;


        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1:
                int arrI[DECLARED_SIZE];
                system ("CLS");
                fill_array(arrI, DECLARED_SIZE, number_used);
                smallest = index_of_smallest(arrI, start_index, number_used);
                cout << "The smallest integer is: " << arrI[smallest] << " ";
                break;
            case 2:
                float arrF[DECLARED_SIZE];
                system ("CLS");
                fill_array(arrF, DECLARED_SIZE, number_used);
                smallest = index_of_smallest(arrF, start_index, number_used);
                cout << "The smallest float is: "<< arrF[smallest] << " ";
                break;
            case 3:
                char arrC[DECLARED_SIZE];
                system ("CLS");
                fill_array(arrC, DECLARED_SIZE, number_used);
                smallest = index_of_smallest(arrF, start_index, result);
                cout << "The smallest character is: " << arrC[smallest] <<" \n";
                break;
            default:
                cout << "That is an invalid choice! Exiting Program";
        }

        cout << "\n\nWould you like to return to the main menu? (Y/N): ";
        cin >> menuLoop;

        while(toupper(menuLoop) != 'Y' && toupper(menuLoop) != 'N')
        {
            cout << "Invalid Choice: Please type (Y/N): ";
            cin >> menuLoop;
        }

        system("CLS");
    }
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    menu();
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: You are using `arrF` in your `case 3` call. You should be using `arrC`.

Comment: [OT]: Note that you may encounter strange behavior with `ans != '-'`: if you enter the int `45` (which is equal to `'-'`).

Answer (score 0):

Your error is here:

```
smallest = index_of_smallest(arrF, start_index, result);
```

Which should be:

```
smallest = index_of_smallest(arrC, start_index, number_used);
```

You were using the wrong array, and you were passing `result` (which was never initialized) instead of `number_used`.